# Word for short-term license

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word or expression for a short term license for an app. Users will pay for a license to use the software for a couple of hours or days. I have considered some words but none seem to be perfect. Here are the main ones, and reservations I have about using them:

**License**

This seems to be the "correct" one, but is usually associated with a perpetual license. And therefore "3 day license" seems a bit like a contradiction, and is also a bit wordy.

**Code / ID**

While this is how it's implemented, and appeals to me as a software developer,  it doesn't seem to describe the actual "item" being sold.

**Pass**

While I think this conveys the idea correctly, it seems to be a little slangy.

**Permit / Ticket**

Refers to a *nonexistent* object. Also see "Code/ID" above.

**Subscription**

Usually means recurring.

Comment: *Pass*, *permit* and *ticket* work well.

Answer (score 1):

Use *token* in the sense of something that gains you access to your software for limited use (somewhat like a subway token).

Comment: Since a token is used and is subsequently not present, it would be troublesome later in the app's life for sentences such as "Your token still has 2 hours left". No? (Though if it weren’t for that I do admit it might sound good.)

Comment: [_Token_](https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/T/token.html) is an overloaded term, but in a network, a token acts like a ticket; in a security system, a token is a card that typically has an expiration.

Comment: +1 Excellent. *Token* is just the type of word to which a one-hour expiry could apply. (Using such a short period of time with the other words would be a little strange.) The more general word, which you used, is just **access**, to which any time period could also be applied. (You purchase *access* to something.)

Answer (score 0):

In general, I agree with Lawrence's comment that *pass* would work quite well. If, however, you still feel that is a little too slangy, perhaps [*lease*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lease) would work as well. I mean in the sense of "Etymology 6" on the wiktionary page--a license for a predefined period of time.